# Color cells when other cell value equals specific value

Tags: excel

The best way to ask this question is to give an example:

in cell `A1` I have value, if the value is "abrakadabra" I want the cells `A2` and `A3` being marked in green color.

How can I do it using the Conditional Formatting?

Thanks

Comment: does the pattern repeat? is it only those two cells?  We need more information.

Comment: only 2 cells for example to catch the idea

Comment: Then your `Applies to: ` is `$A$2:$A$3` and your formula is `=$A$1 = "abrakadabra"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to: **Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
2. Insert formula `=$A$1 = "abrakadabra"`
3. Apply desired format
4. Open Conditional Formatting window again & apply the rule to desired cells (`A2:A3`)

[image]
[image]

Comment: how can i apple that rulls on rows without entering each row rules, can i do it ?

Comment: If you are looking for the same text, you can copy the format over. Although, you will need to adjust the locked cell references (`$`). You will want to unlock the column by removing the dollar sign before all column letters. `$A$1` > `A$1`

Comment: can i do it on existing data ? copy only the formula

Comment: Do not copy the formula, use the `Format Painter` which is located on the home tab top left. The icon is a brush followed by `Format Painter` :)

Answer (score 0):

Select cells A2 and A3, go to conditional formatting, and as rule type, choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". And the formula you can then add $A1="abrakadaba", choose the formatting you want, and click "OK".

[EDIT] Based on comment below, I made the A absolute, but I left the 1 relative, as I assume you want to copy this to other cells below row A.

Comment: Your formula should make `A1` absolute or A3 will look at A2 for abrakadabra.

Comment: Indeed, the A must be absolute, but probably not the 1, as I assume the objective is to extend/autofill  this to other cells below. I edited my answer based on this.